# jquery show hide multiple divs one after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to show multiple divs one after another.

For example, when page loads, it will show:

```
A1
```

When `A1` is clicked, page will show

```
A1
B1
```

When `B1` is Clicked, page will show

```
A1
B1
C1
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this please.

Comment: share the code what u have show far ? use `toggle()` in jquery

Comment: I am new in JQuery and all of this in a separate Div element. like <div id=a value=A1></div> like this

Comment: try to made an effort to make it and show us what is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might get you started.

```js
$('.mydivs').click(function(){
  if ( $(this).next().is(':visible') ) $(this).nextAll().hide();
  else $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.mydivs:not(:first-of-type){display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a1" class="mydivs">Div A1</div>
<div id="b1" class="mydivs">Div B1</div>
<div id="c1" class="mydivs">Div C1</div>
<div id="d1" class="mydivs">Div D1</div>
```

Comment: Damn, beaten to the punch, I'd whipped up a jsfiddle, practically identical to your solution :) https://jsfiddle.net/efreeman79/jahtL9rg/

Comment: Great and many thanks for the solution, Also, it is possible to hide any lower divs when upper divs clicked.

Comment: Glad to help. When you are able, pass it along *(and your point score will go up . . . )*